# CakePHP: Redirect to login from custom component

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

In a custom component I am making API calls. If the API call returns 403 I want to logout the user and redirect to the login. With the following code I get a response object without knowing if the response is a redirect or if the response is containing the data of the request. Besides get I have also other methods implemented in the Component so that I have at the end over 50 times a call to the RestAPIComponent.

Calling the RestAPIComponent

```
public function view($id) 
{
    $resource = $this->__getSingularResourceName();
    $$resource = $this->RestApi->get($id)->json;
    $this->set(compact($resource));
}
```

RestAPIComponent

```
public function get($id = null, array $query = [], $action = null)
{
    $path = (is_null($id) === false) ? $id : '';
    $response = $this->_http->get($path . '/' . $action, $query, $this->_getAuthHeader());
    return $this->_handleResponse($response);
}

private function _handleResponse(Response $response)
{
    if ($response->statusCode() == 403) {
        $this->Cookie->delete(TOKEN);
        $this->Cookie->delete(USER);
        $controller = $this->_registry->getController();
        return $controller->redirect($controller->Auth->logout());
    } else {
        return $response;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check _what_ exactly, _where_ exactly, and _why_ exactly? You really need to add more info, the most essential part, the actual problem, is lacking any details.

Comment: How my changes are clear.

Comment: Sorry, the essential part is still missing. What is important here is where you are actually handling the returned response, it's impossible to give you any proper advises without knowing what exactly happens in that context, and why testing for the type of response is problematic.

Comment: Are you going to use this component in web-services call ?

Comment: Yes. $this->_http->get is a call to the HttpClient.

Comment: Try using using other methods to call the url in cakephp rather than this -- $response = $this->_http->get($path . '/' . $action, $query, $this->_getAuthHeader()); This line also using getAuthHeader();  auth component method.

Answer (score 2):

There may be following reasons behind it, getting the 403 error using  auth component  --
1.It is possible to get a 403 via code. Check this out from the CakePHP docs (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#handling-unauthenticated-requests):  If authenticator returns null, AuthComponent redirects user to  login action. If it’s an ajax request and AuthComponent::$ajaxLogin is  specified that element is rendered else a 403 http status code is  returned.

2.Multiple Ajax calls shouldn't be the causing factor of a 403 error.
  3.The standard routing is handled by CakePHP itself. If you need some  different routing, you should configure this in routes.php. I would say  using .htaccess is only for a really extreme routing need and should be  a last resort.

4.Yes that could be a cause, since you would no longer be logged in, thus get Auth 403s

For more detail -- you could visit the link  [Common reasons behind 403 errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18636412/common-reasons-behind-403-errors)

Comment: AuthComponent does not return 403. Making a request with the HTTPClient returns 403 as the Token I am using is not longer valid.

Comment: Check your App controller there might be few settings related to Auth Component that may be inherited in your case  @Raman seems right at this point.